# Delete Web API return 401

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have delete Endpoint when the user sends a request it returns 401 on test server .it works fine on local

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. 
>   You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the
>   credentials that you supplied

update I tried to give the folder all permission but no used

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Go to the test server and learn which 401.x you hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this how we fixed it

```
<modules>
  <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0"
       path="*"
       verb="*"
       type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
       preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />

</handlers>
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <verbs>
            <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
        </verbs>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Comment: Note that these elements should be in <system.webServer> element in Web.config

Answer (score 1):

I think you should enable `DELETE` verb on IIS by removing `WebDAV`

add this lines on your `web.config`

```
<modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>

<handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
</handlers>
```